# Wildfly - Configure ActiveMQ to use Postgres journal

Tags: postgresql, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I'm trying do setup the ActiveMQ on Wildfly 17.0.1.Final to use Postgresql as journal.

I have the datasource configured, and I'm using it in the application. However, when I configure ActiveMQ Artemis to use the Postgres datasource as a journal I'm having the problem described. Is there something missing in the setup?

Versions:

- Wildfly 17.0.1.Final
- Openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
- PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit

If I use `ExampleDS` as a datasource journal my application starts, but for the Postgresql datasource I'm having the error.

The datasource subsystem:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDS" pool-name="PostgreDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</connection-url>
            <driver>postgresql</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>test</user-name>
                <password>test</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
                <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
            </validation>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

The activemq subsystem:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:7.0">
    <server name="default">
        <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:changeme}"/>
        <journal datasource="PostgreDS" />
        <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="1000"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="queueTESTE" entries="java:/jms/queue/queueTESTE"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

```
10:02:58,137 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) 
SQL STATEMENTS: 
CREATE TABLE large_messages (ID BIGSERIAL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255), EXTENSION VARCHAR(10), DATA OID, PRIMARY KEY(ID))
SQL EXCEPTIONS: 
SQLState: 00000 ErrorCode: 0 Message: CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "large_messages_id_seq" for serial column "large_messages.id"
 SQLState: 00000 ErrorCode: 0 Message: CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "large_messages_pkey" for table "large_messages"
10:02:58,257 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) 
SQL STATEMENTS: 
CREATE TABLE page_store (ID BIGSERIAL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255), EXTENSION VARCHAR(10), DATA OID, PRIMARY KEY(ID))
SQL EXCEPTIONS: 
SQLState: 00000 ErrorCode: 0 Message: CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "page_store_id_seq" for serial column "page_store.id"
 SQLState: 00000 ErrorCode: 0 Message: CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "page_store_pkey" for table "page_store"
10:02:58,321 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
10:02:58,321 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
10:02:58,321 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
10:02:58,322 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
10:02:59,890 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) AMQ224097: Failed to start server: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/PGConnection
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.PostgresSequentialSequentialFileDriver.createFile(PostgresSequentialSequentialFileDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFileFactoryDriver.openFile(JDBCSequentialFileFactoryDriver.java:114)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFile.load(JDBCSequentialFile.java:110)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFile.open(JDBCSequentialFile.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreFactoryDatabase.reloadStores(PagingStoreFactoryDatabase.java:223)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingManagerImpl.reloadStores(PagingManagerImpl.java:300)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingManagerImpl.start(PagingManagerImpl.java:404)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart1(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2757)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:595)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:373)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.jms.JMSService.doStart(JMSService.java:206)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.jms.JMSService.access$000(JMSService.java:65)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.jms.JMSService$1.run(JMSService.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.PGConnection from [Module "org.apache.activemq.artemis" version 2.8.1 from local module loader @10e92f8f (finder: local module finder @7ce3cb8e (roots: /home/rafael/dev/server/wildfly-17.0.1.Final/modules,/home/rafael/dev/server/wildfly-17.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 24 more
```

I can check that 4 tables were created in the public schema when I started Wildfly, but after that the error occurs.

I also added the postgres module to the Artemis module, and now the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to org.postgresql.PGConnection
```

I then added the `<module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />` too, but the same error occurs.

Comment: In my opinion (as a developer on ActiveMQ) this looks like a bug. However, it's hard to say whether the bug is in Artemis or Wildfly. Artemis wants to cast the DB connection to a `org.postgresql.PGConnection` but that's not what Wildfly has provided since it's wrapping the connection with it's own implementation (i.e. `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8`). Have you tried configuring the database integration directly in the messaging subsystem rather than using a datasource? I'm not even sure that's possible in Wildfly, but that's the way it's done for Artemis standalone.

Comment: I did not find another setting in the Wildfly docs, but I'll look for more details.

I changed the database to Mysql, for testing, and it worked. Now I am testing the application to investigate whether it will work in an cluster environment, like Openshift, using JMS with queues in the database.

I'll post on the Wildlfy forum to see if I open an issue, as it seems to be something related to Wildfly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found it is a bug fixed in 2.12.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2626

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to use the regular (non XA) driver:

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
       <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```